# PHP Image upload error with file contains quotes

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm having troubles if I try to upload a file which contains `'` chars if I'm using my file upload page on my web sites provider's server. I'm using `namecheap.com` right now but I don't know what my client will be using later.

Everything is working ok as localhost, even with files containing the quotes.

The biggest problem isn't the failing with upload. It is the white screen which appears when I'm trying to upload files like `"image '2' test.png"`. I mean, now I cannot generate any error messages.

I have debugged a lot and blank screen comes every time I'm using `$_FILES`. So it seems like I cannot do things like `if($_FILES has errors){ echo 'use different file name..'; }`.

So, the whole upload.php crashes if I'm using filenames with '-quotes and I cannot even send error messages or redirect users. I hope someone has any solution to this?

---

Thanks for the help but I still didn't got it to work. I have tried with and without magic quotes, I have tried also to parse quotes from file names but it didn't help either.

However, the problem is bigger than I thought. Because I'll get white page even if I didn't use $_FILES at all! For example: if I generate upload.php file like this:

`<?php
   echo "test";
?>`

and try my html form with a file name containing ', it doesn't even print that test. Only blank screen. Is this server related issue then? It prints that test if I'm using normal file like picture24.jpg.

Comment: Don't even use special chars like `' / " ! @ # $ % \` ~ `

Comment: Try doing a `preg_replace()` for just numbers,letters,periods,hyphens,underscores. Check that the name isn't empty after all that, and if not upload the file. If empty, then don't upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

- `magic_quotes_gpc` Affects HTTP Request data (GET, POST, and COOKIE).
  Cannot be set at runtime, and defaults to on in PHP. See also  `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`.
- `magic_quotes_runtime` If enabled, most functions that return data from
  an external source, including databases and text files, will have
  quotes escaped with a backslash. Can be set at runtime, and defaults
  to off in PHP. See also `set_magic_quotes_runtime()` and
  `get_magic_quotes_runtime()`.
- `magic_quotes_sybase` If enabled, a single-quote is escaped with a
  single-quote instead of a backslash. If on, it completely overrides
  `magic_quotes_gpc`. Having both directives enabled means only single
  quotes are escaped as ''. Double quotes, backslashes and NULL's will
  remain untouched and unescaped. See also `ini_get()` for retrieving its
  value.

Hope this will help you in solving your problem.